# Is it possible to prove that surfaces with compact boundary are homeomorphic by glueing disks to the boundary components?

Tags: algebraic-topology, surfaces, geometric-topology

Let $S_1$ and $S_2$ be two surfaces with compact boundary and the same number of boundary components. Let $M_1$ and $M_2$ be the surfaces obtained by glueing closed disks to the boundary of $S_1$ and $S_2$, respectively. Is there a direct proof that if $M_1$ and $M_2$ are homeomorphic then $S_1$ and $S_2$ are also homeomorphic? I know that this can be done in the compact case using normal forms, as in Massey's book. And if the surfaces are not compact?

Answer (score 3):

If $M_1$ is homeomorphic to $M_2$, then it is homeomorphic via a map preserving the attached disks because we may compose the homeomorphism of $M_1$ and $M_2$ with a homeomorphism that takes the image of the disks attached $M_1$ to the disks attached to $M_2$ (such a homeomorphism exists by isotopy extension). By removing the interior of the attached disks of $M_1$, we have $S_1$ and the restriction homeomorphically maps onto $S_2$.

A similar result will be true in all higher dimensions topologically, but more care is needed in the smooth case. For example, in dimensions above 4 you can attach disks to disks along their boundary and arrive at nondiffeomorphic spheres, so the notions of diffeomorphism and diffeomorphism after capping off boundary components needs refinement (you need to specify how boundary components are capped off).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Would you please give me a reference where I could find the existence of the homeomorphism that maps attached disks of one surface to the other by isotopy extension? Thank you again

Comment: @FernandoOliveira The only thing to prove is that all orientation preserving embeddings of $k$ disjoint disks into a path connected space are isotopic. This is a very easy generalization of the case of 1 disk which is proved by showing that the space of such embeddings is homotopy equivalent to the oriented frame bundle of the manifold.

Comment: Thanks again. I am not a topologist and need this for a paper on surface dynamics I am writing. I think I understand the general idea, but I wouldn't be able to write a proof of the result you mentioned for one disk. Is this proof that the space of such embeddings is homotopy equivalent to the oriented frame bundle of the manifold written anywhere? Any reference would be helpful.

Comment: @FernandoOliveira You can find it in Kupers' lecture notes on diffeomorphism groups of manifolds.

Comment: Thank you for the reference